# The binary operation in Group Theory using C++

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, virtual-functions

So I am doing a project in group theory using C++ template classes. The idea is to encapsulate the concept of a mathematical group. Now a group has a binary operation ϕ: G x G -> G. However, the class definition will not define the function body. That will be done during when a group object is created. So is it best to use a function pointer? When a group object is instantiated, the pointer will be set to the actual binary function.Or should one use polymorphism and define ϕ as a virtual function which will be redefined by a derived class of specific group types(like a permutation group for example).

Comment: Pretty much any of these can work; which is better is going to depend on details both not described, and off topic on stack overflow.

Comment: I would use std::function<G(G,G)> member inside the class, and take the concrete operation in the constructor. This will allow you for example to pass operation as a lambda function. (You will have to use compiler with C++11 support)